# How to prevent your internal project documentation from being pushed to remote repo while it still needs to be tracked locally?

Tags: git, version-control

I have gone through similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them quite satisfy the need.
Using gitignore won't let me track changes of the documentation.
Using submodules, again won't be part of the main repo, and would have to be commited separately.

Another similar question might be if it is at all possible using git to exclude some files/folders only when you push.

To make it more clear, I have a project say `project`

project

|_codefolder1/

|_codefolder2/

|_codefile1

|_etc

|_docs/

what I want is not to push docs/ to production or testing servers at all. But I still want to keep changing and tracking the documentation as it is important to tie specific documentation to a specific version of the product.

Are there any workarounds or am I missing some built-in functionality of git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

> Another similar question might be if it is at all possible using git to exclude some files/folders only when you push.

You can't.

When you run `git push`, that operation does not send *files* to the other Git repository.  That operation sends *commits* to the other repository.

Each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file, like an archive (tar or rar or winzip or whatever).  More precisely, each commit holds all the files that it holds: it either has some file—`docs/foo.txt`—or it does not.  (Commits do not contain folders, only files: the files may have names that have forward slashes in them, and Git knows that the OS requires that storing a file named `docs/foo.txt` requires that Git make a folder named `docs` and then store a file named `foo.txt` in that folder, but as far as the *commit* goes, it's just a *file* named `docs/foo.txt`.)

A file is *tracked* if it is in Git's index.  It is *untracked* if it is not in Git's index.  When you select a *different* commit to check out, Git:

- removes, from its index and your working tree, the tracked files that came out of the *current* commit;
- installs, into its index and your working tree, the files from the newly selected commit: those are now the tracked files; and
- makes the newly selected commit (and branch name if you selected it via a branch name) the current commit (and branch name).

When you build a *new commit*, Git takes all the *tracked files*—all the copies that are in its index—and uses that to make the archive for the new commit.  The set of files in that new commit is thus exactly the files that are tracked, as they appear in Git's index (not necessarily as they appear in your working tree: if you did not `git add` some updated copy, the index copy is the old version).

So if the files are *committed*, they're *tracked*.  If they're not tracked, they're not committed.  The `git push` operation pushes the commits.  That's all there is in Git: that's all you get.

(This is why, e.g., submodules exist, and systems like Google's [repo](/questions/tagged/repo), and so on.)

Comment: Got the point. So seems like if I create a pre-commit hook which -> asks me if i want to push at this point  -> if yes, removes the docs folder from index ->  commits(without docs) is made -> pushes to server -> adds docs folder back to index -> exits the hook and final commit is made.

That is if, it is possible to commit from within the pre-commit hook.

Comment: Or may be do same in pre-push hook.? Will definitely try this and update here.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work: you either had the files in the index and committed them (so they're saved) and then `git push` pushes them (so they're on the other repo too), or you didn't have the files in the index and didn't commit them (so they're not saved) and then `git push` doesn't push them. What you could do, in a pre-push hook, is generate *new* commits that are like the old commits but different, and then push the *new* commits *instead of* the commits that you were proposing to push, and then reject the push from the pre-push hook. But this is a terrible thing to write.

Comment: In the end, you must make two separate histories: one in which these files exist, and one in which they don't. The two separate histories must never meet up, and the best way to ensure this is to have two separate repositories. (You then push commits from just *one* of these repositories to the GitHub site.)

Comment: I ended up `wipe`ing  the files/folders that i don't want in a post-receive hook. I know this is a workaround but works fine for my current need. Thanks for you help and clarity

Comment: That (post-receive hook trick) will also work; it's just kind of hairy to code and hard to get right with all the corner cases that can happen.